# I can not see the "share" button on the forecast page. Can anyone tell me the hack to see that button?

Tags: forecasts-collaborative

[image]

I am supposed to see a share button here. Don't know why I can't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you logged in as the correct user and that you are in Lightning UI. As this will not be applicable in classic UI. Then follow the steps below:

1. Login as User(Say Dan), go to Forecast Tab, click Forecast sharing button.
2. Choose a coworker to share your forecasts with (say Tom).
3. Select an access level: View Only or View and Edit. Users with View and Edit access can make adjustments.
4. Save your changes.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=forecasts3_share_forecasts.htm&type=5

If the sharing icon still does not show up, check the steps below:

1. Go to Setup
2. Open Forecast Hierarchy
3. Look for Dan, Next to his name, click on EDIT MANAGER
4. Verify if the Radio button "Administrators and the forecast manager can share this forecast" is selected.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked.